# Whenever Gem and cron Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash, cron

I followed the instruction on Whenever gems website, and tried following it in both development and on production mode on server.

```
set :output, "/file/to/path/cron.log"
every 1.day, at: '11:59 pm' do
   command "sudo touch /file/to/path"
   runner "Location.transfer_data",:environment => 'production' 
end
```

It doesn't create the file(which is a test for now since I have no data on production).

I have spent hours trying to debug it and `crontab -l` gives me this output

`59 23 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'sudo touch /file/to/path >> /file/to/path/cron.log 2>&1'`

`59 23 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/name && script/rails runner -e production '\''Location.transfer_data'\'' >> /file/to/path/cron.log 2>&1'`

Regards,

Babar Rehman

Comment: How do I edit it now?

Comment: @Babar Did you check just writing `log info` with in  `transfer_data`??

Comment: I used rails console logging and that doesn't show up in the log  file either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, don't know which one solved it in particular but these were the step that I took

1. Added job name to **whenever --update-cron** command

`whenever --update-cron jobName`

2. Restarted the **cron** service

`sudo service cron restart`

3. Gave full access rights to the **log file**

`sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file.log`

Hope it will come in handy for others